# Jquery change numeric values in tables using classes

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change the values in all `<td>` with the class `.price` by multiplying it with 2.
With the jquery code below I'm calling all values (`text`s) with the class `price` but I have trouble finding a way to multiply it and display it in the same `<td>`. 32000 should end up being 64000 and 12000 should end up being 24000.
Help would be much appreciated.

JQUERY:

```
$(".price").each(function() {

                var value = $(this).text();

                if(!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
                    sum += parseFloat(value);
                }
```

HTML:

```
<table>
       <thead>
        <tr>
         <th><span>Item</span></th>
         <th><span>Price</span></th>
        </tr>
       </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
       <td class="name">a</td>
       <td class="price">32000</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
       <td class="name">b</td>
       <td class="price">12000</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use use `.each()` to iterate over the `price` class elements and when you do, use `$(this).text()` to get (and set) the respective element's text. Then it's just a simple matter of multiplying by two with  `* 2`. Like this:

```js
$(".price").each(function() {
  $(this).text($(this).text() * 2)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
HTML:

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><span>Item</span></th>
      <th><span>Price</span></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">a</td>
      <td class="price">32000</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="name">b</td>
      <td class="price">12000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: "Like this"? This is probably the worst answer I've seen you post :).

Answer (score 0):

You can use bit shift for multiple 2 like this

```
$(".price").each(function() {
  $(this).text(parseInt($(this).text()) << 1)
})
```

```js
$(".price").each(function() {
  $(this).text(parseInt($(this).text()) << 1)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
HTML:

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><span>Item</span></th>
      <th><span>Price</span></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">a</td>
      <td class="price">32000</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="name">b</td>
      <td class="price">12000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```